# Is Q_INVOKABLE needed to invoke a public QObject function from QML at all in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I just realized that I can call pretty much any function of an object that is exposed to QML. Now I am curious about Q_INVOKABLE. The Qt5 [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html) state:

> [...] any QML code can access the following members of an
> instance of a QObject-derived class:
>
> - Properties
> - Methods (providing they are public slots or flagged with
>   Q_INVOKABLE)
> - Signals

[Since Qt5](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt-5Features) (In C++) I can invoke any public function of a QObject like a slot, i.e. I do not have to declare them as 'public slot'. Does this mean I can call any method from QML? I cant find anything in the docs.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can invoke any public function like a slot." ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example where you call a non-invokable, non-slot function from QML.

Comment: While trying to provide an example where I call a non-invokable, non-slot function from QML, I realized that its not possible. Wow I dont know how I came to believe that it would work ... :/ Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you have to mark your function of a QObject with `Q_INVOKABLE` unless it's a `public slot` in order to be able to call it from QML.

Both Q_INVOKABLE and the slots keyword register your function with `Qt meta-system`. The difference is that with Q_INVOKABLE *you can return values*.

Comment: But why can I call [QModelIndex::row()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmodelindex.html#row) or [QApplication::keyboardModifiers()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#keyboardModifiers)? Neither of them is a slot or Q_INVOKABLE.

Comment: you can't call them from QML

Comment: By the way, note that QModelIndex is not even a QObject.

Comment: Technically, a slot can also return values. They’re just ignored when the slot is used as slot (connected to a signal) though. Q_INVOKABLE is better style though, in such cases.