# expose C++ class to QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have this code.

```
class Pet
{
  public:
   Pet(const QString& nm)
    : name(nm)
   {}

   const QString& name() const { return nm; }

   private:
    QString nm;
}

class Dog : public QObject, public Pet
{
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Dog(QObject* prnt)
     : QBject(prnt),
       Pet("Tommy")
    {}
}
```

Exposing this to `QML`

```
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setProperty("petDog", new Dog(&engine));
```

// QML Item

```
console.log(petDog.name()) // TypeError: Property 'name' of object Dog(0x0XXXXX) is not a function
```

What is the solution to expose all the methods of a C++ class to QML? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The methods must be known to the meta-object system in order to be invokable from QML. This means a method must be either:

1. a signal (`Q_SIGNAL`), or
2. a slot (`Q_SLOT`), or
3. invokable (`Q_INVOKABLE`).

In Qt 5 the difference between a slot and an invokable method is only that of whether the method is listed as among the slots when you iterate its metaobject data. Other than that, slots and invokable methods are equivalent.

In Qt 5 you can `connect` from C++ to any method, even if it's not a slot/invokable, but such methods are only known to the C++ compiler, [not to QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35335564/is-q-invokable-needed-to-invoke-a-public-qobject-function-from-qml-at-all-in-qt5).

Comment: I like to point out, looking at the provided example, you also may set class members as `Q_PROPERTY`.

Comment: @maxik And what has that got to do with invokable methods?

Comment: The provided example has a instance member called `name` with getter. In my opinion this suits a `Q_PROPERTY` much better than an `Q_INVOKABLE`. Setting it this way the method `name()` becomes also invokable.

Comment: @maxik Cool, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: for further reading look here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html#exposing-properties